# Can I get the element value if any unique ID is not present using Javascript/Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I need how to access an element value if there is no `unique id selector` is present using `Javascript/Jquery` . 
I am explaining my code below :

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-6" style="height: 100%;border-right: 1px solid;">
  <div style="text-align: center; border-bottom:1px solid;">
    <p class="lead">New Student Registration</p>
    <a href="institute_list.php?type=REGISTRATION" id="btnRegistration"><img src="assets/img/registration.jpg" height="120" width="180" /></a>
  </div>
  <div style="text-align: center">
    <p class="lead">Online Admission</p>
    <a href="institute_list.php?type=ADMISSION" id="btnAdmission"><img src="assets/img/admission.jpg" height="120" width="180" /></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6" style="padding-top: 70px;">
  <div style="text-align: center;">
    <p class="lead">Registered User Login</p>
    <a href="build/index.php" target="_blank" id="btnAdmission"><img src="assets/img/login.png" height="150" width="150" /></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here If I wanted to get the value of `p` tag `i.e-Online Admission` or any of `p` tag value from them how can I get it even there is not present any such type of `id selector`.

Comment: By using their class to select them? You should read jQuery basics. `$('p.lead')`

Comment: just an addition to @Zenoo comment - this returns an array of objects because `$('p.lead')` has multiple DOM elements matching the selector

Answer (score 0):

> Here If I wanted to get the value of p tag i.e-Online Admission

If want to get the first `p`'s value then simply use `querySelector`

```
var output = document.querySelector("p.lead").textContent;
```

```js
var output = document.querySelector("p.lead").textContent;

console.log(output);
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-6" style="height: 100%;border-right: 1px solid;">
  <div style="text-align: center; border-bottom:1px solid;">
    <p class="lead">New Student Registration</p>
    <a href="institute_list.php?type=REGISTRATION" id="btnRegistration"><img src="assets/img/registration.jpg" height="120" width="180" /></a>
  </div>
  <div style="text-align: center">
    <p class="lead">Online Admission</p>
    <a href="institute_list.php?type=ADMISSION" id="btnAdmission"><img src="assets/img/admission.jpg" height="120" width="180" /></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6" style="padding-top: 70px;">
  <div style="text-align: center;">
    <p class="lead">Registered User Login</p>
    <a href="build/index.php" target="_blank" id="btnAdmission"><img src="assets/img/login.png" height="150" width="150" /></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or, if you want to get  other `p.lead`'s value, then you can **use the index** of that `p` as selector

If want to get the first `p`'s value then simply use [eq](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

```
var output = $("p.lead:eq(0)").textContent; //New Student Registration

var output = $("p.lead:eq(1)").textContent; //Online Admission
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` inside div.

```js
$('div').find('p').each(function (index, element) {
console.log($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-6" style="height: 100%;border-right: 1px solid;">
  <div style="text-align: center; border-bottom:1px solid;">
    <p class="lead">New Student Registration</p>
    <a href="institute_list.php?type=REGISTRATION" id="btnRegistration"><img src="assets/img/registration.jpg" height="120" width="180" /></a>
  </div>
  <div style="text-align: center">
    <p class="lead">Online Admission</p>
    <a href="institute_list.php?type=ADMISSION" id="btnAdmission"><img src="assets/img/admission.jpg" height="120" width="180" /></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6" style="padding-top: 70px;">
  <div style="text-align: center;">
    <p class="lead">Registered User Login</p>
    <a href="build/index.php" target="_blank" id="btnAdmission"><img src="assets/img/login.png" height="150" width="150" /></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

By using map function, you will get all the values p.lead values one by one. Try it:

```
$('p.lead').map(function () {
    $(this).text();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since, you want the content of `p` elements so why don't you simply use the element selector to select all the `p` elements and then loop over to it and get its text content.

```js
$('p').each(function(){
  var pContent = $(this).text();
  console.log(pContent);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-6" style="height: 100%;border-right: 1px solid;">
<div style="text-align: center; border-bottom:1px solid;">
<p class="lead">New Student Registration</p>
<a href="institute_list.php?type=REGISTRATION" id="btnRegistration"><img src="assets/img/registration.jpg" height="120" width="180"/></a>
   </div>
    <div style="text-align: center">
    <p class="lead">Online Admission</p>
    <a  href="institute_list.php?type=ADMISSION" id="btnAdmission"><img src="assets/img/admission.jpg" height="120" width="180"/></a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6" style="padding-top: 70px;">
    <div style="text-align: center;"> 
        <p class="lead">Registered User Login</p>
        <a href="build/index.php" target="_blank" id="btnAdmission"><img src="assets/img/login.png" height="150" width="150" /></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try

```
  var x = document.querySelectorAll("p");
  console.log(x[1].innerHTML);
```

```js
var x = document.querySelectorAll("p");
console.log(x[1].innerHTML);
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-6" style="height: 100%;border-right: 1px solid;">
  <div style="text-align: center; border-bottom:1px solid;">
    <p class="lead">New Student Registration</p>
    <a href="institute_list.php?type=REGISTRATION" id="btnRegistration"><img src="assets/img/registration.jpg" height="120" width="180" /></a>
  </div>
  <div style="text-align: center">
    <p class="lead">Online Admission</p>
    <a href="institute_list.php?type=ADMISSION" id="btnAdmission"><img src="assets/img/admission.jpg" height="120" width="180" /></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6" style="padding-top: 70px;">
  <div style="text-align: center;">
    <p class="lead">Registered User Login</p>
    <a href="build/index.php" target="_blank" id="btnAdmission"><img src="assets/img/login.png" height="150" width="150" /></a>
  </div>
</div>
```